# How to make a cancel function thru code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i really need your ideas and help for this called Cancel Function.
However this project wasn't mine so its really hard to trace the codes plus it is used as codeigniter.

controller(layout.php)

```
  function addprint($id){  
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('printer','printer','required|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('quality','quality','required|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('paper_size','paper_size','integer|required|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity','quantity','integer|required|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('date_printed','date_printed','required|xss_clean');
      if($_POST && $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
          $data['success'] = false;
            $data['vrequests'] = $this->layout_model->get_requests_print($id); 
              $this->load->view('print_layout.php', $data);
        }
        else{
          $data['vrequests'] = $this->layout_model->get_requests_print($id); 
          $this->load->view('print_layout.php', $data);
        }
      }

   function saveprint(){
          $user_session = $this->session->all_userdata();

          $data['username'] = $user_session['username'];
             $data = array();

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('printer','printer','required|xss_clean');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('quality','quality','required|xss_clean');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('paper_size','Paper Size','required|xss_clean');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity','quantity','integer|required|xss_clean');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('date_printed','Date Printed','required|xss_clean');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('amount','amount','integer|xss_clean');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('tr_number','TR Number','integer|xss_clean');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('check_paid','Check Paid','integer|xss_clean');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //error if invalid
            $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
            $data['success'] = false;
            $request_id  = $this->input->post('id');
            $this->addprint($request_id);
        }
        else
        {
            //valid data
            $printer = $this->input->post('printer');
            $quality = $this->input->post('quality');
            $paper_size  = $this->input->post('paper_size');
            $request_id  = $this->input->post('id');
            $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');
            $date_printed = $this->input->post('date_printed');
            $user_session = $this->session->all_userdata();
            $is_paid = $this->input->post('check_paid');
            if($is_paid == 1)
            {
             $amount = $this->input->post('amount');
             $tr_amount = $this->input->post('tr_number');
            }
            else{
              $amount = '';
              $tr_amount = '' ;
            }

            $data = array(
                'printer'       =>  $printer,
                'quality'       =>  $quality,
                'paper_size'    =>  $paper_size,
                'quantity'      =>  $quantity,
                'is_paid'       =>  '1',
                'request_id'    =>   $request_id,
                'date_printed'  =>  $date_printed,
                'user_id'       => $user_session['id'],
                'amount'        =>  $amount,
                'tr_number'     => $tr_amount);
            $data2 = array(
                'is_printed'    => '1');

            $this->layout_model->print_layout($data);  
            $this->layout_model->update_layout_request($request_id,  $data2);
            $this->index();     
        }
              //$data['printer'] = $this->input->post('printer');
              //$data['quality'] = $this->input->post('quality');
              //$data['paper_size']= $this->input->post('paper_size');
              //$data['quantity']= $this->input->post('quantity');

              //$this->load->view('print_layout.php', $data);
      }
```

Models(layout_model.php)

```
      function print_layout( $data)
{

  $this->db->insert('prints',$data);

    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}

  function update_layout_request($request_id ,$data2)
{   
    $this->db->where('id', $request_id);
    $this->db->update('requests', $data2);
}
```

views(print_layout.php)

```
 <?php //first form?>

                    <div class="paper">
                        <center>
                            <span style="color: green">
                            <?php 
                               if(isset($success)){
                                    if($success){
                                        echo "Reservation Successful!";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo '<span style="color: red">'.$errors.'</span>';

                                    }
                                }

                            ?>
                            </span>
                        </center>
                        <h1>Add to Print :</h1>
                        <hr/>
                            <?php echo form_open('layout/saveprint'); ?>
                            <?php echo form_hidden('id',$vrequests->id);?>
                            <?php echo form_hidden('id',$vrequests->id);?>
                            <p>
                                <label>Printer:</label>
                                <select name="printer" id="printer">
                                  <?php $printers = Printer::all(); ?>
                                  <?php foreach($printers as $printer):?>
                                     <option value="<?=$printer->id?>"><?=$printer->printer_name?></option>
                                  <?php endforeach;?>
                                </select>
                              </p>
                              <p>  
                                <label>Quality:</label>
                                <select name="quality" id='quality'>
                                  <option value="black">Black</option>
                                  <option value="colored">Colored</option>
                                </select>
                              </p>
                              <p>  
                                <label>Paper Size:</label>
                                <select name="paper_size" id="paper_size">
                                  <?php $papers = Paper::all(); ?>
                                  <?php foreach($papers as $paper):?>
                                     <option value="<?=$paper->id?>"><?=$paper->paper_name?></option>
                                  <?php endforeach;?>
                                </select>
                              </p>
                              <p>  
                                <label>Quantity:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"  />
                              </p>
                              <p>
                                <label >Date Printed:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="date_printed" id='date_needed' />
                              </p>
                              <p>  
                                <label>Paid?:</label>
                                <input type="radio" name="check_paid" id="check_paid" value='1' /> YES
                                <input type="radio" name="check_paid" id="check_paid" value='0' />  NO
                              </p>

                              <p id='amount_hide' style="display:none" >  
                                <label>Amount:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
                              </p>
                              <p id='tr' style="display:none">  
                                <label>OR No.:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="tr_number" id="tr_number" />
                              </p>
                              <span class="response"></span>

                              </p>           
                              <p>
                                <div class="inline">
                                 <span style="padding: 9px;"><input type="submit" value="Print" /></span>
                                 <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/layout/index" style="text-decoration:none;">
                                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="button">
                                  </a>
                            </div>
                              </p>
                        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

so this time I want to make a cancel function that can be put to database and can be viewable on the website's table.

thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean cancel? cancel a transaction? if confirmed, commit it?

Comment: @kevinabelita yup a cancel transaction..

Comment: this is a code for INSERT into PRINTS database... i would to create an INSERT into PRINTS CANCEL database.

Comment: i haven't used codeigniter for years, but the [user manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html) regarding commit/cancel transactions is pretty straightforward and should be easy to implement on your code